# How to check values of adjacent items in a list? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

I have a list of list that looks something like this

```
let pixels = [
 [0,0,0,0]
 [0,0,0,0]
 [0,0,0,0]
]
```

and I would like to iterate through this list and create a list of the adjacent items for each item. In this example the output I would want from pixels[0][0] is: [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 0, undefined, 0, 0]. But when I run my code I get I get an error

The code cannot read pixels[-1][-1], I just want it to read it as undefined and not crash the whole program.

```js
let pixels = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
]

function adjacent(i1, i2) {
  const yep = [pixels[i1 - 1][i2 - 1], pixels[i1 - 1][i2], pixels[i1 - 1][i2 + 1], pixels[i1][i2 - 1], pixels[i1][i2 + 1], pixels[i1 + 1][i2 - 1], pixels[i1 + 1][i2], pixels[i1 + 1][i2 + 1]]
  return yep
}

console.log(adjacent(1,4))

console.log(adjacent(-1,-1))
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You can not access an `undefined`'s `[-1]` property.

Comment: if `i1` is less than or equal to 1, the folllowing example will throw an error: `pixels[i1 - 1][anything]`. Try a condition to avoid this kind of issue.

Answer (score 4):

When `i` is out of range, `pixel[i]` is `undefined`, and `undefined[anything]` is an error.

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to suppress these errors.

```js
let pixels = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
]

function adjacent(i1, i2) {
  const yep = [pixels[i1 - 1]?.[i2 - 1], pixels[i1 - 1]?.[i2], pixels[i1 - 1]?.[i2 + 1], 
    pixels[i1]?.[i2 - 1], pixels[i1]?.[i2 + 1], pixels[i1 + 1]?.[i2 - 1], 
    pixels[i1 + 1]?.[i2], pixels[i1 + 1]?.[i2 + 1]
  ]
  return yep
}

console.log(adjacent(1, 4))

console.log(adjacent(-1, -1))
```

Comment: Damn you. I did ]?[ and failed.

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah, the syntax isn't consistent. That syntax would confict with the ternary operator.

Comment: I would have beat you had I not spent time to make a working snippet ;)

Comment: Yeah, thank you for that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use && to test the first element exists

```js
let pixels = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
]

function adjacent(i1, i2) {
  const yep = [
  pixels[i1 - 1] && pixels[i1 - 1][i2 - 1], 
  pixels[i1 - 1] && pixels[i1 - 1][i2], 
  pixels[i1 - 1] && pixels[i1 - 1][i2 + 1], 
  pixels[i1]     && pixels[i1][i2 - 1], 
  pixels[i1]     && pixels[i1][i2 + 1], 
  pixels[i1 + 1] && pixels[i1 + 1][i2 - 1], 
  pixels[i1 + 1] && pixels[i1 + 1][i2],
  pixels[i1 + 1] && pixels[i1 + 1][i2 + 1]]
  return yep
}

console.log(adjacent(1,4))

console.log(adjacent(-1,-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using optional chaining, you can use two loops to generate the adjacent coordinates rather than manually writing out each possibility, which is easier to maintain.

```js
let pixels = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
]

function adjacent(i1, i2) {
  const res = [];
  for(let deltaY = -1; deltaY <= 1; deltaY++)
    for(let deltaX = -1; deltaX <= 1; deltaX++)
      if(deltaY != 0 || deltaX != 0)
        res.push(pixels[i1 + deltaY]?.[i2 + deltaX]);
  return res;
}

console.log(...adjacent(1,4))

console.log(...adjacent(-1,-1))
```